# Is it possible to have two different looks for details>summary tag in one document

Tags: html, css, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I would like to have two different looks for details>summary tag in one document.

The first one should look like this:

[image]

It is done through CSS style and the code looks like this:

```
<style>

details>summary { list-style-type: none; outline: none; cursor:     pointer; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}

details>summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none; }

details>summary::after{ content: '+ '; text-align: Right}

details[open]>summary::after{ content: '- '; text-align: Right;}

details>summary {margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3); font-weight: bold;}

details[open]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
    
details[]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);font-weight: bold;}
</style>
```

The second look should be this:

[image]

With the code:

```
<style>
details>summary { list-style-type: none; outline: none; cursor:pointer; }

details>summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none; }

details>summary::before{ content: '+ '; text-align: Right}

details[open]>summary::before{ content: '- '; text-align:Right;}

details>summary {margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; font-weight: bold;}

details[open]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px;}
    
details[]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px; }
</style>
```

I tried to create classes for these looks however ended up with this:

[image]

Which is a basic look of the detail tag.

The code for the classes looks like this:

```
<style>
.mainD{
    details>summary { list-style-type: none; outline: none; cursor:     pointer; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}

    details>summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none; }

    details>summary::after{ content: '+ '; text-align: Right}

    details[open]>summary::after{ content: '- '; text-align: Right;}

    details>summary {margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3); font-weight: bold;}

    details[open]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
    
    details[]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);font-weight: bold;}
}
 
.secondaryD{
    details>summary { list-style-type: none; outline: none; cursor:pointer; }

    details>summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none; }

    details>summary::before{ content: '+ '; text-align: Right}

    details[open]>summary::before{ content: '- '; text-align:Right;}

    details>summary {margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; font-weight: bold;}

    details[open]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px;}
    
    details[]>summary { margin-bottom: 20px; }
}
</style>
```

The code for the  details is here:

```
<details> <summary  style="margin-left:3vw; font-weight:bold; " ><h3 style="font-size: 1.05em;"><sup>1</sup>What is this ID?</h3></summary>
<p  style="margin-left:5vw">This is the content of the details tag.</p>
</details>
<details> <summary  style="margin-left:3vw; font-weight:bold; " ><h3 style="font-size: 1.05em;">1.&nbsp;What is this ID?</h3></summary>
<p  style="margin-left:5vw">This is the content of the details tag.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: @AdamScot Hi, I added the details and summary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Plain CSS doesn't support style nesting, so the above styling doesn't do anything thus the default details styling is applied.

## Solution

Below is one way to achieve your goal. Simply replace the details tag selector with the appropriate class selector.

```css
.mainDetails>summary {
  list-style-type: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.mainDetails>summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

.mainDetails>summary::after {
  content: '+ ';
  text-align: Right
}

.mainDetails[open]>summary::after {
  content: '- ';
  text-align: Right;
}

.mainDetails>summary {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mainDetails[open]>summary {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.mainDetails[]>summary {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.secondaryDetails>summary {
  list-style-type: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.secondaryDetails>summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

.secondaryDetails>summary::before {
  content: '+ ';
  text-align: Right
}

.secondaryDetails[open]>summary::before {
  content: '- ';
  text-align: Right;
}

.secondaryDetails>summary {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.secondaryDetails[open]>summary {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.secondaryDetails[]>summary {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<details class="mainDetails">
  <summary style="margin-left:3vw; font-weight:bold; ">
    <h3 style="font-size: 1.05em; display:inline"><sup>1</sup>What is this ID?</h3>
  </summary>
  <p style="margin-left:5vw">This is the content of the details tag.</p>
</details>
<details class="secondaryDetails">
  <summary style="margin-left:3vw; font-weight:bold; ">
    <h3 style="font-size: 1.05em; display:inline">1.&nbsp;What is this ID?</h3>
  </summary>
  <p style="margin-left:5vw">This is the content of the details tag.</p>
</details>
```